# Not authorised on database to execute command - MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have recently migrated from mLab to MongoDb Atlas. Now, when I try updating the connection string in my Node.js app I am unable to post a new user form to the database. I recieve the following error:

```
"not authorised on database to execute command { insert: "users"..."
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
For example, say:
Username = john (all admin read write permissions have been given)
Password = hello
Database cluster = dogs
```

Firstly, when I connected the string below then no database was shown:

```
mongodb+srv://john:hello@dogs-juria.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Then I edited the string to change ‘test’ to ‘dogs’:

```
mongodb+srv://john:hello@dogs-juria.mongodb.net/dogs?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I now see the database on my app, however, if I now try submit a new user form from my web page, it shows the error mentioned above.

Comment: Can you mongo shell to your Atlas collection and insert something that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with updating url in my container-based cloud Platform as a Service (PaaS)